# How to make accurate timer

Tags: ios, timer

In my Xcode application I have a button that when pressed does about 200 lines of code. I think it would be nice to show the user the time of execution of that function. I already know how to make a simple "second" timer, but I would be needing a timer that goes to the thousandths of a second. Can anyone help? Please ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? How do you do a "second" timer now?

Comment: @24GHz do you want to the time taken for execution?

Comment: Thanks for your replies but I just figured it out. I took the date before processing and then took the date after execution and multiplied it by 1000 to get ms.

Comment: I believe you could close your question as it's now answered in full (or you could post an answer to your own question, possibly helping others pondering the same thing).